# Validation Rule to Restrict date within current fiscal year?

Tags: formula, validation-rule, date

I need help creating validation rule to restrict date between the Current Fiscal year of the company.

Say, the user should be able to only select dates between Oct 1 to September 30 of the following year only.

Can someone please help creating this formula?

So, I have tried this:

```
AND(
    MONTH( Organization_date__c ) >= 10,
    YEAR(Organization_date__c) = YEAR(TODAY()),
    OR(
        MONTH(Organization_date__c) <= 9,
        YEAR(Organization_date__c) = YEAR(TODAY()) + 1
    )
)
```

But still this doesn't restrict the selected date.

Need help, if someone can help me write this formula correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, you should [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far and point out a specific part that you are having trouble with (there is a difference between "help me" and "do it for me"). If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be the better resource to help get you started.

Comment: Thanks for adding what you've tried. I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to remember with validation rules is that they fire when the result of the formula is `true`. This is the opposite of typical developer intuition, so I like to think of them as "invalidation" rules instead.

Your formula needs to tell us when data is *invalid*.

While you could re-arrange the functional parts of your current attempt to make this work, I think that it would be easier (and less typing) to just do straight comparisons with dates (instead of trying to break out the date components and use them).

```java
OR(
    /* date is beyond 9-30 of next year */
    /* The DATE() function takes year, month, and day, in that order */
    Organization_date__c > DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) + 1, 9, 30),

    /* date is prior to 10-1 of this year */
    Organization_date__c < DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 10, 1)
)
```

Notice that in contrast to your initial attempt which tells you if your target field is within the
(year), October 1  - (year + 1), September 30 range,
this formula is telling you if your target field is *outside of that same range*.

Outside of the range = an invalid date
The goal of the validation rule formula is to tell you when data is invalid
so this should satisfy your requirement.

Also note that thanks to De Morgan's Laws, you *could* do the inverse and have the core of your formula describe a date being inside of a given range  (`<` becomes `>=`, `OR()` becomes `AND()`, etc..., and you'd wrap the entire formula in a `NOT()`). However, I feel that approach is harder to read, reason about, and maintain.

Using `TODAY()` here would present a problem though. If you need to go back and edit a record from the previous fiscal year, you would also need to update the Organization date. This strikes me as something you don't want to do. You probably want to use the `CreatedDate` of the record to determine what fiscal year it belongs in (or use some other date that is only set once).